# Is it possible to concatenate in the middle of a view bags property in asp.net core?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core

I am rebuilding an old vb/web forms application with asp.net core. I have 5 columns, one for each day of the week. `Shift_Monday_Target`, `Shift_Tuesday_Target` etc. So in my view I have a variable that gets the day, and I wanted to concatenate it in the viewbag so it will change every day. The previous architect of the application achieved this in their sql query.

But I am using linq, and I'm having trouble translating the syntax from sql to linq. So I decided to try to get the desired result by manipulating my view instead. Which approach is the better approach and which one is even possible?

this is my attempt inside my view.

```
<strong style="color:white">@(ViewBag.PracticeTarget?.Shift_+"DayOfWeek"+_Target ?? "")</strong>
```

Here is my variable to get the day of the week.

```
var DayOfWeek = DateTime.Now.DayOfWeek.ToString();
```

and here is my viewbag.

```
ViewBag.PracticeTarget = db.TblShiftInfo.FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: why not use a dictionary?

Comment: Share us your old implementation and result. You may consider sharing us the sql and we could share you the linq query.

Comment: That would be great! This is the sql.      Dim strQuery As String = "Select Shift_QA_Text as 'ShiftQAText', Shift_Name as 'NewShiftName', Shift_" + DayofWeek + "_Target as 'ShiftTarget' from tbl_Shift_Info where Shift_ID = @ShiftID"

Answer (score 0):

If the day of the week is only useful in the UI, then either could work.

I personally find Razor syntax a PITA to debug and parse quickly compared to C#.

Also note, since it is Razor, it's always done server side. So performance is going to be close.

You also mentioned day of the week, for each column. In that case I would do the "heavy" work once, and then access the computed values by index. Either as a property for whatever you bind to the grid or just another property in the model / view:

```
var culture = CultureInfo.CurrentCulture;            

// This will be Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday
var days = Enumerable.Range((int)DayOfWeek.Monday, (int)DayOfWeek.Friday)
            .Select(s => culture.DateTimeFormat.GetDayName((DayOfWeek)s)).ToList<string>();
```

And I'll assume you are looping through objects for the table creation?

```
for(int i = 0; i <= shiftDays.Count - 1; i++)
{
    <strong style="color:white">@(ViewBag.PracticeTarget?.Shift_ + days[i] + _Target ?? "")</strong>
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried your solution and I get the same error "The name  _Target does not exist in the current context." It appears to be not concatenating at all and treating "Shift_ + days[i] + _Target" as three different names.

Comment: When debugging, does your viewbag **have** those properties? Shift_ and _Target are weird names, Maybe it should be: `ViewBag.PracticeTarget?.Shift + "_" + days[i] + "_" + ViewBag.PracticeTarget?.Target ` ? (At this point, we don't have enough code to make much more than educated guesses...

Comment: I did! So I'm realizing that I'm going to have to handle it first in my linq/sql query. The properties I have in my viewbag are Shift_Monday_Target, Shift_Tuesday_Target etc. This is my current query I'm trying to call.     
      db.Database.OpenConnection();
                var command = db.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "Select Shift_" + DayOfWeek + "_Target as 
                'ShiftTarget' from tbl_Shift_Info";
                command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                ViewBag.PracticeTarget = (command.ExecuteScalar());

Comment: @qpc4ever Hm, so that's in the database as some sort of type column? Hopefully with a (fk) ? But if that's how it is in the database then this entire question seems irrelevant? As you wouldn't have to mess with Razor syntax at all

Comment: That's why I was asking which is the better approach. The actual data in the db that I want to access is called Shift_Monday_Target. So I thought by getting the day of the week I can just concatenate and switch out the day of the week for the correct day of the week, so it changes each day. I know I can do a series of condition statements, but that seems like a messy approach. There has to be a better way! It seems like this sql would work.  "Select Shift_" + DayOfWeek + "_Target as 'ShiftTarget' from tbl_Shift_Info" because then I can just call ViewBag.PracticeTarget.ShiftTarget, but no luck.

Comment: @qpc4ever worth noting: Razor is in the backend. It gets rendered server side and then sent to the client. But yes, the better route would be much like I posted (no ability to test fully right now). Generate view models, then loop through them in Razor...